# How come local types always get an even address

Tags: c++, function, call

Given that example code:

```
void func( char arg)
{
    char a[2];
    char b[3];
    char c[6];
    char d[5];
    char e[8];
    char f[13];
    std::cout << (int)&arg << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)&a << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)&b << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)&c << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)&d << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)&e << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)&f << std::endl;
}
```

How comes that with every call i get a result similar to that:

```
3734052
3734048
3734044
3734080
3734088
3734072
3734056
```

With every address being an even number?
And why are the addresses not in the same order like the variables are in the code?

Comment: Size of data and byte boundaries, perhaps?

Comment: They're even divisible by 4. Modern CPUs don't like byte aligned accesses much.

Comment: I think what @JoachimIsaksson says also (it not preferably) applies to the stack

Comment: Padding for performance.

Comment: "And why are the addresses not in the same order like the variables are in the code?" -- Why would they?

Comment: This might help to understand why aligned memory is helpful - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Comment: And that's why the *value* of pointers is mostly meaningless in C++. The only thing you can do with pointers is compare for equality, and under certain restrictive situations for order. ((To be pedantic, you can always compare pointers for order, too, with `std::less`, but the order is only *meaningful* for subobjects.))

Comment: @KerrekSB You can also use pointer values for pointer arithmetic when you are using arrays or certain structures.

Comment: @Jordan the qualifier was "in C++". Unlike in C, where you often see pointer arithmetic, C++ has a more powerful type system and containers that make it easy to avoid pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> And why are the addresses not in the same order like the variables are
>   in the code?

The first element in the structure is guaranteed to be at the same location as the structure itself (if they were members of one), but the other elements are not guaranteed to be in any order.  The compiler will order them appropriately to allow it to use the least amount of space, typically.  For local variables, where they are located in memory is completely up to the compiler.  They could all be in the same area (likely since it would take advantage of locality), or they could be all over the map (if you have a crappy compiler).

> With every address being an even number?

It is placing them along word boundaries.  This makes memory access faster than if they are not placed on word boundaries.  For example, if `a` were to be placed on the last byte of one word, and the first byte of another:

```
|             WORD 1                |                WORD 2             |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
                           |  a[0]  |  a[1]  |
```

Then accessing `a[0]` and then `a[1]` would require loading 2 words into the cache (on a cache miss for each).  By placing a along a word boundary:

```
|             WORD 1                |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|  a[0]  |  a[1]  |
```

A cache miss on `a[0]` would result in both `a[0]` and `a[1]` being loading at the same time (decreasing the unnecessary memory bandwidth).  This takes advantage of the principle of locality.  While it is certainly not required by the language, it is a *very* common optimization done by compilers (unless you use preprocessor directives to prevent it).

In your example (shown in their order):

```
3734044 b[0]
3734045 b[1]
3734046 b[2]
3734047 -----
3734048 a[0]
3734049 a[1]
3734050 -----
3734051 -----
3734052 arg
3734053 -----
3734054 -----
3734055 -----
3734056 f[0]
3734057 f[1]
3734058 f[2]
3734059 f[3]
3734060 f[4]
3734061 f[5]
3734062 f[6]
3734063 f[7]
3734064 f[8]
3734065 f[9]
3734066 f[10]
3734067 f[11]
3734068 f[12]
3734069 -----
3734070 -----
3734071 -----
3734072 e[0]
3734073 e[1]
3734074 e[2]
3734075 e[3]
3734076 e[4]
3734077 e[5]
3734078 e[6]
3734079 e[7]
3734080 c[0]
3734081 c[1]
3734082 c[2]
3734083 c[3]
3734084 c[4]
3734085 c[5]
3734086 -----
3734087 -----
3734088 d[0]
3734089 d[1]
3734090 d[2]
3734091 d[3]
3734092 d[4]
```

Assuming no other data is being assigned to those holes, it would appear whatever settings you have with your compiler is making sure that all of your arrays start on a word boundary.  It isn't that it is adding space between the arrays (as you can see there is no space between `e` and `c`), but that the first element must be on a word boundary.  This is implementation specific and not at all required by the standard.

Comment: There are no structures in his code, so I don't see the relevance of your first point.  And adding padding to a `char` will not normally affect performance, and if it does, it will be negatively (by making the total data set span a larger address range, and thus reducing locality).

Comment: @JamesKanze I misread the question when I started my answer (thought it was a `struct`, not a function).  I left it there and added the point about variables as it does not hurt the answer (and answers a potential follow-on question).  I didn't say anything about padding, though.  What are you referring to there?

Comment: His compiler seems to be placing some sort of padding between the variables he has declared.  I don't know why, but it doesn't look like it has anything to do with optimization.  (If optimization were an issue, one would expect the largest variables, or at least those with the strictest alignment requirements to be allocated first.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Ah, I think I see what you are referring to.  I didn't mean for "padding" to be interpreted that way.  I've adjusted the wording to be more clear.

Answer (score 4):

In general, this has nothing to do with the scope of the variables.  It has to do with the processor.

A processor that has a word size of 16 bits, likes to fetch it's variables from even addresses.  Some 16-bit processors only fetch from even addresses.  So, fetching from an odd address will require two fetches, thus doubling the number of memory accesses and slowing down programs.

Other processors may have broader requirements.  Many 32-bit processors like to fetch data on 4-byte boundaries.  Again, very similar to the 16-bit processor example above.

Some processors do have the ability to fetch data at odd addresses.  These are generally 8-bit processors.  Some bigger processors cheat and fetch more bytes but ignore all but the requested ones (depending on where the byte lines within the alignment space).

The compiler can allocate local function variables anywhere it chooses, in any order it chooses.  The compiler may want to place the frequently accessed variables close together.  It may choose not to allocate memory for variables and use registers.  It may allocate a variable on the stack, or it may allocate the variable from a completely different memory area.  In general, the location of variables doesn't matter as long as the functionality of the program is still correct.

Comment: Can you name a processor today which cannot fetch a single byte at an odd address?  As long as only `char` are involved, adding alignment is just as likely to have a negative impact as a positive one.

Comment: ARM7 processor, in 8/32-bit mode, actually fetches 32-bits and discards 24 bits.  ARM7TDMI in thumb mode fetches 16 bits and disregards 8 bits.

Comment: Actually, most processors usually fetch entire cache lines. Fetching 8 bits from a cache line isn't that much harder than fetching 32 bits from a cache line.

Comment: @For that matter, on the processors which do it, when fetching 32 bits and extracting a single byte, it probably doesn't matter which byte you're fetching.  Alignment really only comes into play when you're trying to fetch something larger than a byte in a single cycle.

Answer (score 1):

> With **every** address being an even number?

This might be true on the platform/compiler you are using.  C++ makes no such guarentee.  It is likely to work this way, but pointer addresses are **not defined to be even** and you cannot have compliant code that counts on pointers being divisible by 2.

Comment: There's no _undefined_ behavior, unless he starts getting fancy, and attempts to increment a `char*` from one array into the next.  The order and alignment of individual variables is not specified, but not specified doesn't mean undefined behavior.

Comment: @JamesKanze whether addresses are divisible by 2 or 4 is undefined, and cannot be counted on.  Not that his usage is undefined, the behavior is.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but... C++ uses the term "undefined behavior" in a very specific way, and there isn't any here; the behavior is unspecified, not undefined.

Comment: @JamesKanze does that work better, or is there some other nuance I missed?

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Yep, that's a good formulation which doesn't mix it with the term UB.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's the way your implementation decided to do things.
Even changing some compiler options might change things.  Sun
CC and g++ *do* generate odd addresses, and more or less in the
order you would expect.  Why VC++ doesn't, I can only guess, but
some possible reasons could be:

- They add extra bytes around each variable, for error checking.
  In such cases, there might be some advantage in aligning the
  extra bytes.
- They might generate the variables in the order they occur in
  an internal hash table.

But these are just guesses; there are doubtlessly other reasons
which could cause the behavior you're seeing as well.

Comment: When I compiled in debug-mode with VS 2012 there was far more space between variables. So you are wright with your first point.

Comment: VC++ in debug mode will typically pad arrays with space before and after (set to a constant value) the array to help flag out of bounds errors.  These are not typically included in release builds.