# Meaning of applying bitwise or with a pointer address

Tags: c, pointers, bitwise-operators

While I was [reading this code](https://github.com/armon/libart/blob/master/src/art.c#L20) of an ART implementation, I did not understand the reason behind calling SET_LEAF to do bitwise or with pointer address

```c
   #define SET_LEAF(x) ((void*)((uintptr_t)x | 1)) 

   *ref = (art_node*)SET_LEAF(make_leaf(key, key_len, value));
```

I also saw

```
#define IS_LEAF(x) (((uintptr_t)x & 1))
```

which looks at the least significant bit to check if it was a leaf node.
Now the whole argument would work only if the pointer address is an even number (0x100504080).

```
2 | 1 // 3
3 | 1 // 3
```

Is it guaranteed that the pointer address would always be an even number across all the architecture?

Edit:
Possible duplicate [How come local types always get an even address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889938/how-come-local-types-always-get-an-even-address)

Question on top: Can i safely assume that the pointer would always be starting from event number no matter what kind of data I have?

Comment: I edited the question to reduce the confusion. initially SET_LEAF is called which does x | 1 and then  IS_LEAF is called to check x & 1 == 1. This would work only if the pointer address is an even number. My question was is it guaranteed? @MarcoBonelli

Comment: This looks to my like undefined behavior... Im not sure but the part where they forward the address by one byte look suspicious to me

Comment: This library does not look like it is meant to be perfectly portable too all architectures, it supports some non-x86 as a bit of an afterthought (with a significantly worse non-SSE2 code path). Still a valid question of course, but I'm noting this so that you know what to expect: speed over portability.

Comment: The code is avoiding allocating some mostly wasted space by using the l.s.b. of the pointer value to store the flag. These pointers ultimately come from calls to `calloc()`, so the code is assuming that such pointers will be even when converted to integers. (Side note: The Linux kernel uses similar tricks in its implementation of red-black trees.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is technically undefined behavior, but considering the fact that they use `_mm_movemask_epi8`, they probably don't care about portability. In x86 with standard glibc malloc, the returned address should always be aligned to a word (8 bytes in 64 bit), which means that it's always even.

Comment: The `_mm_movemask_ep18` calls are in preprocessor conditional code. There is non-x86 code as well. The code does assume that `malloc` (or `calloc`) will return an even address though.